# How to keep session alive after a launch request when using aws-sdk2

Tags: amazon-web-services

Here is a code snippet that I am using for a lambda function but I am using the sdk v2. When I run it, the skill times out just after the launch request.

I have tried `.keepSession()` and `.listen()`

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
      canHandle(handlerInput) {
          return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type==='LaunchRequest';
                             },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speakOutput = 'Hello,Welcome to DXC\'s google.How may I help you?';
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak(speakOutput) // The text passed to speak, is what Alexa will say.
    .getResponse();
},
};
//asks for employee id
const EmployeeIdIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {

        console.log(handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name);
     return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
     && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'EmployeeIdIntent'
   },
   handle(handlerInput) {
    const speakOutput = 'Please tell me your employee id';
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak(speakOutput) // The text passed to speak, is what Alexa will say.
    .getResponse();  
   },
};
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My first advice is to add a `.reprompt(REPROMPT_MESSAGE)` at the LaunchRequest to remind the user to answer.
You can also try to add

`return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speakOutput)
      .withShouldEndSession(false)
      .getResponse();`

I normally use it when I need to close the session (with true in the argument).

You can find more information in the documentation:
https://developer.amazon.com/es/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#response-format

I hope It will help you!